# Preventing Zoom in Phonegap + JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, touch, zooming

I'm building a PhoneGap + JQuery Mobile app, but I can't seem to prevent it from zooming in with a double click.  I followed the tips listed at http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/01/17/mobile-web-phonegap-html-dev-tips/, specifically by adding:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

Does anyone know of a solution for zooming?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />
```

This is what I use and I don't get any zooming behavior.

Here is the Apple documentation for the `viewport` meta tag: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

Comment: Ok, I think what the problem was might have been related to either:
1)  Caching
2)  Using the "-webkit-user-select" settings suggested at http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/01/17/mobile-web-phonegap-html-dev-tips/

At some point zoom stopped happening, but after I cleared the cache and removed "-webkit-user-select".  Not sure which triggered it.  (Probably cache)

Answer (score 1):

Place "user-scalable=no" in to your meta tag

like this

```html
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

This is the best way to stop zoom in mobile, Its work for me in phonegap

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution does not seem to work in iOS10, this does:

```
// stop ios bounce and zoom 
document.ontouchmove = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
};
```

This will stop move events reaching the root element/browser